# JMeter - Unable to run PSKill / PSExec commands through OS Process Sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to kill java process running on a remote PC using PSKill.exe, which is working fine through a batch file. However, it is not working while running through OS process sampler. Attached screenshot of OS sampler.

I am getting below error message, appreciate if you can help me with a solution

---

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-06-14 14:25:31 BST
Load time: 16
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "PsKill.exe" (in directory "c:\Support"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType:

### DataEncoding: null

Regards,
Ram
[image: JMeter - OS Sampler Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it a little bit, i.e. provide **full path to the PsKill executable** via "Command" input, like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Full Path]

As "Working directory" is a different beast, you need to explicitly "tell" JMeter where `PsKill.exe` lives.

You might also want to add `-accepteula` key just in case license agreement pops up on first execution.

Another option is using [Windows PowerShell Remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands#windows-powershell-remoting), this way you can utilize built-in PowerShell functionality and won't have to use external utilities. Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Excellent!
Thank you very much Dmitri. 
It is working after changing the command path to "c:\support\PSKill.exe"